# Rails: belongs_to association through a form not populating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I'm working on the controller for my class, `Project`. It has a `belongs_to` relationship with `Client`.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but when I create a new project through the form, it has a `name` assigned to it, but no `fee` and no `client_id`.

Here's the relevant code:

**Project controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      redirect_to projects_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private 

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :feee, :client_id)
  end
end
```

**projects/new view**

```
<div id="newproject-form">
    <h1>Create a project</h1>
    <%= form_for @project do |p| %>
        <div id="newproject-form-input">
            <ul>
                <li><%= p.label :name, "Project name: " %><br>
                <%= p.text_field :name, size: 40 %></li>

                <li><%= p.label :fee, "Fee: " %><br>
                <%= p.text_field :fee %></li>

                <li><%= p.label :client, "Client name: " %><br>
                <%= collection_select(:client_id, :name, current_user.clients, :id, :name) %></li>

                <li><%= p.submit "Create project", class: "form-button" %>, or <%= link_to "Cancel", 
                root_path %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Project model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

end
```

Comment: `params.require(:project).permit(:name, :feee, :client_id)` is the extra 'e' in fee a typo or in your actual code? Might be your issue with fee

Comment: Please add you Client model also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `collection_select` on the form builder:

```
# change this
<%= collection_select(:client_id, :name, current_user.clients, :id, :name) %>
# to this
<%= p.collection_select(:client_id, current_user.clients, :id, :name) %>
```

By using the FormBuilder `p` you are telling the `collection_select` that you are editing a Project object (see `p.object` to return the object of the form builder).

---

If you look at the `collection_select` documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select):

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

If you call `collection_select` by its own (not from a form builder, provided by the `form_for` method), you have to give as first argument the object's name. In your case, it would have been `collection_select(:project, :client_id, #etc.)` to generate params like `params[:project][:client_id]`.

Comment: won't work, he named his form_builder 'p', not 'f' :P

Comment: This worked, thanks. And thanks for the brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 1):

For fee to work, you need to fix your typo in your `project_params`

For client_id, try this instead:

**inside views/projects/new**

```
 <%= collection_select(:project, :client_id, current_user.clients, :id, :name) %>
```

OR

```
<%= p.collection_select(:client_id, current_user.clients, :id, :name) %>
```

when you use `collection_select` the first two parameters are the object and attribute the collection describe (in this case your `project` object and the `client_id` attribute) so when you write `collection_select(:client_id, :name, current_user.clients, :id, :name)` Rails is actually receiving an object that looks like `{ client_id: {name: 'Something'} }` which you're completely ignoring, while my code adds :client_id to the project object which is what your code expects.

Using a form builder (in this case your `p` object) lets you omit the 'object' param because the form builder already knows what object it's building the form for.

Comment: Doh! Changed the fee typo. Thanks.